# Copy unique values from two columns into a third column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a master list of orders in a spreadsheet.

Column A lists all orders.   Column B lists a subset of all orders.  If both lists were small, I could manually do this but I have hundreds of records to look through.

What is the best way to find values from Column A that do not exist in Column B, and place them in Column C?

Visually, I am looking to create a Column C like this:

```
Column A       Column B       Column C
A1             A3             A1
A2             A5             A2
A3                            A4
A4
A5
```

Note that I am not seeking to merely highlight unique values in Column A, but I am looking to copy those unique values into a new column (C).

Comment: Your requirement is simple COMPARE column A with B and extract unique values in Column C. So better edit the TITLE.

Comment: And check the solution I've posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$100,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(1/(ISNA(MATCH($A$1:$A$100,$B$1:$B$100,0))*ROW($A$1:$A$100)*($A$1:$A$100<>""))),ROWS($1:1))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Wish this formula could copy to column C without the empty cells.

Comment: @acoder I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Here's my [example sheet](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Cwq1iaWWUfN0iR4-2-KMDzrjgKsPGnJh).  This may be an OpenOffice thing, but I'm left with blank values between cells in column C.

Comment: @acoder Perhaps you mean `Libre Office` as I do not believe `Open Office` has the `IFERROR` function.  In any event, if I open the file you uploaded in Excel, there are no blanks in column C -- it displays as shown in my screenshot.  So, clearly, it is a Libre Office thing.  Unfortunately, the two are not identical.

Comment: My mistake, it is Libre Office.  Ended up just find/replacing the blank rows in gedit, then pasting back into the sheet in a different column.

Comment: @acoder Glad you got it fixed. I have limited experience with Libre Office.  It seems it may handle formula generated arrays differently from Excel, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Your formula works fine in Libra Office however, thanks for that.

Comment: @acoder Good to know.  Thanks for the follow-up

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy with a "helper" column. In **D1** enter:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$B$1:$B$5,0)),1,"")
```

and in **D2** enter:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,$B$1:$B$5,0)),1+MAX($D$1:D1),"")
```

and copy down.  Column **D** marks each row that contains useful data with a unique ID.  Column **D** tells use first get data from row#1, then get data from row#2, then get data from row#4

Then in **C1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$5,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),D:D,0)),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest you a simple VLOOKUP Formula, will compare both Columns A & B and extract unique vales in Column C.*

[image]

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,$B$2:$B$6,1,FALSE)),A2,"")
```

*Hope this help you.*

Comment: Do you know why it's adding an empty cell in Col C?

Comment: Yeah,, I do,, since the Formula is matching like A2 with B2 , A3 with B3 and so down wards. Therefore found A1, A2 & A4 not available in Column B are Unique.

Comment: Ah, got it.  I wish there was a way to remove the "blank" values in Col C.  Filtering isn't working for me since there is a formula in the cell and not exactly empty, but also not showing any data.