# Copy DUPLICATE values from two columns into a third column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This is similar to another post:

[Copy unique values from two columns into a third column](https://superuser.com/questions/1290810/copy-unique-values-from-two-columns-into-a-third-column)

I am looking to do the Opposite of this: Here's the gist...

Two separate things I am looking for from 5 ranges of data.

#1 involves two ranges: W17:W49, G17:G49 (in the attached image, this is MRC/GAP Member, and Life & Disability Member):
If a number appears in both ranges, the duplicate number should print in a 3rd column. (in the attached image, range L4:M11)

#2 involves five ranges: W17:W49, U17:U49, G17:G49, C17:C49, E17:E49 :
If a number appears in Range W AND either Range C or Range E
OR a number appears in Range U AND Range G
the duplicate Number should print in a 3rd column (in the attached image, range N4:O11)

(in the attached image, these columns are MRC/GAP Member, MRC Member, Life & Disability Member, Life Member, Disability Member)

[image: FileView]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar example that you can adap to your needs.  The two lists are in column **A** from **A1** through **A15** and column **B**.

In **C1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$15,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$999)/(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$1:$A$15,B:B,0))),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

Comment: What does the 15,6 mean in Aggregate(15,6,Row...)

Comment: @throwzone2001  See:  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df